# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar varias funciones asíncronas SIN acoplarlas?

Tags: nodejs, express

Quiero tener un conjunto de funciones asíncronas pero que estén [desacopladas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoplamiento_inform%C3%A1tico), es decir, que las funciones sean independientes unas de otras. Y después, tener una función síncrona que las invoque.

Por ejemplo:

```
function readFiles() {
  file1()
  file2()
  file3()
}

function file1 () {
  fs.readFile('file1', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data)
  })
}

function file2 () {
  fs.readFile('file2', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data)
  })
}

function file3 () {
  fs.readFile('file3', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data)
  })
}
```

**Por poner sólo un ejemplo de funciones asincrónicas**, la idea es que no importa qué función concreta se use, puede ser una consulta de mongoose o cualquier otra ejecución de una función asincrónica.

Una manera en que lo resuelvo es invocar la siguiente función después de que se ejecuta el callback:

```
function readFiles() {
  file1()
}

function file1 () {
  fs.readFile('file1', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data)
    file2()
  })
}

function file2 () {
  fs.readFile('file2', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data)
    file3()
  })
}

function file3 () {
  fs.readFile('file3', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data)
  })
}
```

Pero no estoy cómodo, hace que una fuerte dependencia entre las funciones lo cual es mala idea para el mantenimiento a futuro.

¿Sí me explico lo que pregunto?

Comment: Esto ya fue resuelto previamente [acá](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45163/c%C3%B3mo-sustituir-un-callback-de-una-funci%C3%B3n-asincr%C3%B3nica-por-promise-nodejs-6-9-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa Promise.All

```
let promises = [];
promises.push(asyncA(done));
promises.push(asyncB(done));
promises.push(asyncC(done));

Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
     finalFunction();
}
```