# ¿Cómo sustituir un callback de una función asincrónica por promise? Nodejs 6.9.1

Tags: nodejs, promesas

He investigado sobre alternativas para ejecutar una serie de funciones asincrónicas una después de otra. La manera en que lo hago ahorita es como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
function readFiles () {
  file1()
}

function file1 () {
  fs.readFile('file1', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data)
    file2()
  })
}

function file2 () {
  fs.readFile('file2', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data)
    file3()
  })
}

function file3 () {
  fs.readFile('file3', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data)
  })
}
```

Este ejemplo es con el fin de mostrar funciones asincrónicas, que puede ser cualquiera.

Como se muestra, `readFiles()` sólo ejecuta `file1()`, el cual al finalizar su ejecución asincrónica va a invocar a `file2()`. Cuando `file2()` termine de ejecutar, invoca a `file3()`. Y así podría continuar hasta *N* funciones.

Lo que quiero es quitar esa fuerte dependencia haciendo algo como esto:

```
function readFiles () {
  file1()
  file2()
  file3()
  fileN()
}

function file1 () {
  fs.readFile('file1', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data)
    // Ya no invoco nada aqui
  })
}

// Resto de funciones
```

Pero de ese modo se ejecutarán las funciones conforme se vayan completando, no en el orden secuencial esperado debido a que son asincrónicas.

Veo que las promises pueden servir, pero no logro comprenderlas o.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con Promises podes realizar esto de una manera fácil. Básicamente tenes que comprender bien la diferencia entre Callbacks y Promises. Si lo pensas en Español, Promise es igual a Promesa. Creo que una manera de que lo entiendas fácil es si te digo que: "File1 es una promesa de una lectura del archivo file1". Una promesa puede estar:

- Pendiente de ser cumplida
- Cumplida
- Rechazada

Fijate [acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promesa) para mas información acerca de las Promises. En cuanto al ejemplo que envías, podes realizarlo de la siguiente manera.

```
// Creamos una función que permita leer un archivo con Promesas
function readFile(fileToRead){
  // La función devuelve una promesa
  return new Promise (reject, resolve) {
    // Se procede a leer el archivo
    fs.readFile(fileToRead, 'utf8', function (err, res) {
      // Si hay un error la promesa no se cumple (se rechaza)
      if (err) return reject(err);
      // Si esta todo bien, la promesa se resuelve (se cumple)
      return resolve(res);
    });
  }
}

// Procedemos a leer los archivos
Promise.all([readFile('file1'), readFile('file2'), readFile('file3')]).then(function(data){
    console.log('file 1');
    console.log(data[0]);

    console.log('file 2');
    console.log(data[1]);

    console.log('file 3');
    console.log(data[2]);
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});

// Tambien puedo leerlos uno por uno
readFile('file1').then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    return readFile('file2');
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    return readFile('file3');
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

La segunda manera es mas entendible, pero la primera espera la respuesta de las 3 lecturas para terminar